# Predictive Intelligence Web - Customize calls with catalog custom attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to create a new Predictive Content Page as described below:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/predictive_intelligence/predictive_intelligence_prerequisites/getting_started_with_web_personalization/creating_personalization_for_a_site/creating_personalization___configuring_the_page/

but I cannot figure out how to filter data with additional parameters via querystring. For example, the integration code is something like this:

```
http://.../a/v2/.../shop/recommend.js
```

where **shop** is the page name. But i would like to filter result by shop id with something like this:

```
http://.../a/v2/.../shop/recommend.js?shopId=123
http://.../a/v2/.../shop/recommend.js?shopId=456
```

where **shopId** is a custom attribute in the products catalog.

How can I accomplish this?
I've read the following documentation but I cannot find anything regarding custom parameters...

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/predictive_intelligence/predictive_intelligence_prerequisites/getting_started_with_web_personalization/creating_personalization_for_a_site/get_personalization_code/customizing_the_calls/

Best regards

Comment: were you able to add custom attributes at the end?